# use average of a colomn in another table

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-update, average

I have two tables:

```
CARMAKES
id, name, avg_sold_for

SALES
carmake_id, price
```

What I want to do is use a single SQL statement to do the following:
For all rows in CARMAKES, the avg_sold_for field should show the average of all price fields from SALES, where carmake_id matches the given id from CARMAKES.

so with the example:

```
CARMAKES
id, name, avg_sold_for
0, "Toyota", 0
1, "Nissan", 0

SALES
carmake_id, price
0, 10
1, 20
0, 30
0, 20
```

I want to update the CARMAKES table to be

```
CARMAKES
id, name, avg_sold_for
0, "Toyota", 20
1, "Nissan", 20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE CARMAKES
SET avg_sold_for = (SELECT SUM(price) / COUNT(carmake_id) 
                    FROM SALES WHERE CARMAKES.id = SALES.carmake_id)
```

**OR**

```
UPDATE CARMAKES C 
INNER JOIN (SELECT carmake_id, (SUM(price) / COUNT(carmake_id)) avg_sold_for
            FROM SALES GROUP BY carmake_id) A ON C.id = A.carmake_id
SET C.avg_sold_for = A.avg_sold_for
```

Comment: Thanks, I used your first suggestion which worked just perfect.